# How can I get CPU usage and/or RAM usage of a *THREAD* in C# (managed code)?

Tags: c#, performance, multithreading, memory-management, cpu-usage

I know how to get CPU usage and memory usage for a process, but I was wondering how to get it on a per-thread level. If the best solution is to do some P-Invoking, then that's fine too.

Example of what I need:

```
Thread myThread = Thread.CurrentThread;

// some time later in some other function...

Console.WriteLine(GetThreadSpecificCpuUsage(myThread));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an example which does what you want
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/processescpuusage.aspx

Answer (score 11):

As said, memory use cannot be answered since that is an attribute of the process as a whole, but CPU use:

```
Process p = Process.GetCurrentProcess(); // getting current running process of the app
foreach (ProcessThread pt in p.Threads)
{
    // use pt.Id / pt.TotalProcessorTime / pt.UserProcessorTime / pt.PrivilegedProcessorTime
}
```

Comment: Note that ProcessThread  is not directly connected to .NET thread.
See also:   
https://stackoverflow.com/a/24085127/6841224  or
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ed307fa4-5717-44e2-91ec-f219abf29dad/convert-processthread-object-to-thread?forum=csharplanguage

Answer (score 7):

You can't get memory usage per thread because memory is shared between all threads in a process. How would the OS know whether you allocated memory in one thread and used it in another. And what would it mean?

Comment: But typically TLS is only used to hold a reference to an object in the shared memory.

Comment: It's not the OS the one that has to determine the usage of a thread, is the framework itself.

Comment: @JuanCarlosDiaz OS or framework doesn't matter, the same problem applies anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple program that launches 5 threads that consume different amounts of CPU and then matches up what managed thread is consuming what amount of CPU.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Threading;

class Program
{
[DllImport("Kernel32", EntryPoint = "GetCurrentThreadId", ExactSpelling = true)]
public static extern Int32 GetCurrentWin32ThreadId();

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Dictionary<int, Thread> threads = new Dictionary<int, Thread>();

    // Launch the threads
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        Thread cpuThread = new Thread((start) =>
        {
            lock (threads)
            {
                threads.Add(GetCurrentWin32ThreadId(), Thread.CurrentThread);
            }

            ConsumeCPU(20 * (int)start);
        });
        cpuThread.Name = "T" + i;
        cpuThread.Start(i);
    }

    // Every second wake up and see how much CPU each thread is using.
    Thread monitoringThread = new Thread(() =>
        {
            Stopwatch watch = new Stopwatch();
            watch.Start();

            while (true)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
                Console.Write("\r");

                double totalTime = ((double)watch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
                if (totalTime > 0)
                {
                    Process p = Process.GetCurrentProcess();
                    foreach (ProcessThread pt in p.Threads)
                    {
                        Thread managedThread;
                        if (threads.TryGetValue(pt.Id, out managedThread))
                        {
                            double percent = (pt.TotalProcessorTime.TotalMilliseconds / totalTime);
                            Console.Write("{0}-{1:0.00} ", managedThread.Name, percent);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    monitoringThread.Start();
}


// Helper function that generates a percentage of CPU usage
public static void ConsumeCPU(int percentage)
{
    Stopwatch watch = new Stopwatch();
    watch.Start();
    while (true)
    {
        if (watch.ElapsedMilliseconds > percentage)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(100 - percentage);
            watch.Reset();
            watch.Start();
        }
    }
}
}
```

Note that it is possible that the CLR will change the native thread that the managed thread is executing under. However, in practice I am not sure how often this actually happens.