# cpu usage of a thread

Tags: c#, .net, performancecounter

how to get the cpu usage of a thread in .net in c#

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/processescpuusage.aspx
-first result from google-

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get the cpu usage per thread on windows (win32)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1393006/how-to-get-the-cpu-usage-per-thread-on-windows-win32)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get CPU usage and/or RAM usage of a \*THREAD\* in C# (managed code)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/934497/how-can-i-get-cpu-usage-and-or-ram-usage-of-a-thread-in-c-sharp-managed-code)

Answer (score 3):

Check [How to get the cpu usage per thread on windows (win32)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1393006/how-to-get-the-cpu-usage-per-thread-on-windows-win32)  and  [GetThreadTimes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683237(VS.85).aspx) you can use [PInvoke](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32.getthreadtimes) for that. Another similar post on SO: [How can I get CPU usage and/or RAM usage of a *THREAD* in C# (managed code)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/934497/how-can-i-get-cpu-usage-and-or-ram-usage-of-a-thread-in-c-managed-code) So this is duplicate.