# Get CPU and RAM usage for a thread in an application pool

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have a thread (in a WCF webservice) launched in a remote application pool and I want to get CPU and RAM usage of this thread.

How can I do that?

Comment: Have you seen this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3958571/cpu-usage-of-a-thread

Comment: Yes ! Not helpful :/

Comment: Not even this? http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10258/How-to-get-CPU-usage-of-processes-and-threads It might be helpful if you post whatever code you have been able to come up with