# Get running thread by name from ProcessThreadCollection

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, process

After searching on Stack Overflow questions and some googling, I still not getting it.

I'm aware that you can check if a single thread is running with "Thread.isAlive()" method, but I want to check if a particular "FooThread" is still running between all running threads from current process, and if not, call the method that starts it.

```
//somewhere in the code, on another Project/DLL inside solution
private void FooThreadCaller()
{
    Action act = () => fooFunction();
    Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(act));
    t.Name = "FooThread";
    t.Start();
}
//...
Process proc = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess();
ProcessThreadCollection threads = proc.Threads;
bool ThreadExists = false
foreach (ProcessThread item in threads)
{
    // if item.Name == "FooThread", then ThreadExists = true...
    // so, if !ThreadExists then call FooThreadCaller() and so on.
}
//...
```

Since the ProcessThread class doesn't have a "Name" property (like System.Threading.Thread does) but only ID, and I only know the thread name ("FooThread") not the ID, how could I check if "FooThread" is running/alive?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Even if this was possible it would not be a good idea. If the thread was just in the process of exiting you would perceive it as still running. This is inherently racy. Track this information yourself. When FooThread shuts down, make not. When it starts, make note.

Comment: You are doing something very, very wrong.  Any "is a thread still running test" is useless, it might not be running a nanosecond later.  Good thing it doesn't work.

Comment: These are great comments, but it's also worth pointing out that the OP's actually checking to see if the thread is *not* running.

Comment: Yeah, I agree with @Slider345 . I just want to check if the thread is NOT running, so I could start it. Since the thread is flag-triggered at startup time (when I read a configuration file and the thread's flag was previously set as true, for an example), I just want a way to launch it at runtime without having to restart my program.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As mentioned in the other answers, the ProcessThread and the Thread objects are different.  Your dll is creating it's own Thread object, but then it throws away it's reference to that object.  Then later on your are querying the OS (through System.Diagnostics) for that thread and expecting the same level of access you had before as the thread's creator.

Instead, you should save the references to your Thread objects as you create them.  Maybe your dll could implement a public static collection object which you would then add your thread objects to as you create them.

Then outside of your dll you could loop through the collection and check the names and status of each Thread.

Answer (score 3):

`ProcessThread` represents an operating system-level thread, while `Thread` represents a .Net managed thread. An operating system-level thread doesn't have a name but a unique ID (just like a process does).

Instead of checking in the list of current thread if your thread is still running, you probably should change the logic of your code. For example, you could keep a boolean containing the state of your thread and update it when it starts/ends.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is a way to do that. A `ProcessThread` represents an *OS* thread. A `Thread` represents a *managed* thread inside your application. There isn't really a relationship between the two. Furthermore, the mapping of `Thread` and `ProcessThread` is NOT 1:1, as in, a `ProcessThread` can represent multiple `Thread`s.