# How can I read the name of a thread in a C# application?

Tags: c#, multithreading, class, object, properties

I'm working on a multithreaded application, written in C#.
I would like to verify if a thread is already running or not.

You might think "How easy can that be?", but there seems to be a catch:

Hereby a screenshot of my threads-window:

[image]

As you can see, there's a thread with ID 42940 with the "Name" property "Notify Icon".

Now I'm debugging the following piece of source code:

```
foreach (ProcessThread thread in currentThreads)
{
    log.Debug($"Info about thread:Name=[], ID=[{thread.Id}], IsAlive=[]");
}
```

Using a breakpoint, I've arrived at the thread with ID 42940. When I show this thread in the watch-window, this is what I see:

[image]

As you see, the "thread" object (of the ProcessThread class) seems not to have a "Name" property, although this is very well visible in the "Threads" window.

I would like to access that "Name" property in the source code.
How can I do that?

**Edit:**
Apparently, nine years ago somebody asked [the same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24084958/get-running-thread-by-name-from-processthreadcollection). Seeing how basic my question is, I can't imagine that during nine years, nothing has been developed in order to counter this issue. Does anybody have information on that? In case it's not tackled yet, are there any plans getting this done?

**Edit (seems not to be working after all):**

I have now the following code in my project:

```
foreach (ProcessThread thread in currentThreads)
{
    var hThread = OpenThread(THREAD_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION, false, thread.Id);
    SetThreadDescription(hThread, "Naam van de thread");
    var testdesc = GetThreadDescription(hThread, out string desc);
    var testGetThreadId = GetThreadId(hThread);
    log.Debug($"Info about thread:Name=[{desc}], ID=[{thread.Id}], description=[{testdesc}], testGetThreadId=[{testGetThreadId}]");
```

Nevertheless the value of the `desc` variable keeps being an empty string.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get running thread by name from ProcessThreadCollection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24084958/get-running-thread-by-name-from-processthreadcollection)

Comment: @PaulF: apparently, nine years ago it was not possible finding a thread, based on its name. Is this still the case or has a problem been found for that? If not, are there any plans tackling this problem? (It looks to basic to me that I can't imagine nothing being done in order to solve this)

Comment: With `Microsoft.Diagnostics.Runtime` you can create snapshot and iterate over heap objects find the thread and read "_name" field

Comment: @Selvin: I'm afraid I tried this already, but there's a catch: that library means that an additional library needs to be installed (amongst others) on the customer's PC. In top of that, that library (if I'm not mistaking) is called `*unsafe*.dll`, it's not easy convincing a customer adding an unknown library on his system with such a name :-)

Comment: Then obviosuly you need to build the name of threads by you own ... Itering of thread should be only useful for debugging ...  depends on this seems like a bad design

Comment: Did you want `Thread.Name` from `System.Threading.Thread` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.thread.name?view=net-7.0

Comment: @Charlieface: there seem to be different things: I wanted the name of the threads, as can be retrieved from the "Threads" window. In order to do this, I am learning to work with `SetThreadDescripton` and `GetThreadDescription` (but it's not going great, as you can see in my last edit here). In top of this, I need to link `ProcessThread` and `System.Threading.Thread` (for which I've written a new question).

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you have to used the Windows APIs: [`OpenThread`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-openthread) and [`GetThreadDescription`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-getthreaddescription). I have tried to search these APIs in the dotnet source code, but only `SetThreadDescription` is used.

```
const int THREAD_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION = 0x0800;
[LibraryImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
private static partial IntPtr OpenThread(int dwDesiredAccess,
         [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)] bool bInheritHandle, int dwThreadId);
[LibraryImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
private static partial IntPtr GetThreadDescription(IntPtr hThread,
         [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] out string ppszThreadDescription);
```

```
foreach (ProcessThread thread in currentThreads)
{
    var hThread = OpenThread(THREAD_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION, false, thread.Id);
    GetThreadDescription(hThread, out string desc);
    log.Debug($"Info about thread:Name=[{desc}], ID=[{thread.Id}], IsAlive=[]");
}
```

**Edit from [Dominique](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4279155/dominique):**
As the previous answer seems not to work, the following lines of source have been added and are working successfully:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
private static extern int GetThreadId(IntPtr hThread);
...
var testGetThreadId = GetThreadId(hThread);
log.Debug($"Info about thread:ID=[{thread.Id}], testGetThreadId=[{testGetThreadId}]");
```

=> this proves that working with `DllImport` is working fine. Now we need to establish why the `GetThreadDescription()` call always returns an empty string.

**Edit2:**
There is one weird thing in the "exports" list of that "kernel32.dll" file:

```
C:\"Program Files"\"Microsoft Visual Studio"\2022\Enterprise\SDK\ScopeCppSDK\vc15\VC\bin\dumpbin.exe /EXPORTS C:\Windows\System32\kernel32.dll

...
769  300 000255C0 GetTempPathW
770  301 00020CF0 GetThreadContext
771  302          GetThreadDescription (forwarded to api-ms-win-core-processthreads-l1-1-3.GetThreadDescription)
772  303 0003BA40 GetThreadErrorMode
773  304 0003BA60 GetThreadGroupAffinity
...
```

Maybe that `forwarded` stuff causes the function not to work?

Comment: Unfortunately, my computer seems not to know about `LibraryImport` nor `SetLastError`, but `MarshalAs` and `UnManagedType` are recognised. For your information, the target framework of my application is `.NET Framework 4.6.1`. The highest framework I have installed on my PC is version `4.8`.

Comment: I've replaced the `LibraryImport` by this but the threadname seems not to be found: `[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]`.

Comment: I also tried, using the other "kernel32.dll", but also here no success: `[DllImport("C:\\Windows\\SysWOW64\\kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]`.

Comment: The result of `var test = GetThreadDescription(...)` equals 2^28, what does this mean?

Comment: I'm using .net 7 and I can obtain some names, let me try a .net framework app.

Comment: Thanks. In the meantime I've done some extra experiments, as described in my edit of your answer.

Comment: Em.. 0x10000000 means success. I noticed [the comment](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/d59af2cf097acb100ad6a9cba652be34be6f4a2e/src/mono/mono/utils/mono-windows-thread-name.c#L3) on the source code that called the `SetThreadDescription` function, which mentions a method of setting thread names before Windows 10, but it is only visible to the debugger. The .Net Framework also existed before Windows 10, and I suspect that these threads were using this method to set thread names, that's why `GetThreadDescription` returns nothing.

Comment: Am I reading this correctly? So, using Visual Studio, I can see the name of a thread. In order to access that name outside of the Visual Studio debugging environment, I need to have set the name, using the `SetThreadDescription` or that won't work, even not if I download the "api-ms-win-core-processthreads-l1-1-0.dll` file in my System32 folder? So, there is no possibility to read the thread's name outside of the Visual Studio environment and I can't use it inside my program.

Comment: ... in fact this whole discussion comes down to the fact that the expression `this_thread.Name=...` only sets the name, while `SetThreadDescription` does two things: setting the name and doing something else. Do you know what that something else might be?

Comment: You haven't read [this article](https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2015/10/26/thread-naming-in-windows-time-for-something-better/) in the comment yet, have you? It explains how the debugger obtains the name column. In short the old code did not use `SetThreadDescription` to set the name of the thread, so `GetThreadDescription` is useless in this situation.

Comment: I have read the article now, I understand why it's not working, but unfortunately I can't simply alter my thread handling in order to force the usage of `SetThreadDescription`, as that part of the code is located within a library and the `Thread` object is programmed as being `private` :-(